# How to scale/distribute this kind of DFS algo questions into a distributed system

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, scaling

I'm preparing the Google interview and found some follow-up

Take the below question for example.
What if the input size is really large which could not be done on a single machine.

My idea is to chunk it into many pieces.
However, the difficulty is I have no idea how to reduce/merge the answers.

Any idea or direction of this sort of problems.

https://leetcode.com/problems/max-area-of-island/

```
Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had a really, really big map. Then you'd break it up into rectangular pieces and give each instance a piece:

- Each instance would then run something similar to the solution to the thing you linked from LeetCode.
- It would know what it's own entirely surrounded islands are, and from that it would know the largest of those and report them to the leaderboard.
- It would have a list of its own islands that are adjacent to an edge, and the indices of adjacency, which is just a pair for each of four edges or null if the island doesn't touch that edge. Basically this covers the case where there's a piece of land that stretches across the whole instance.
- It would know which map it's got, and where to query about its edge islands. It's just gonna say "I've got land at this edge from here to here. You?"
- It would need to be able to return a list of adjacent islands (size, indices, other adjacencies) to another instance.
- It would need to query next-hop instances until all multi-map islands are discovered.
- You'd need a special instance that merges all the results into a global leaderboard.
- For extra credit you need to identify when two or more instances have counted the same large island and remove duplicates. Maybe just store the edge info in a hash.

Comment: I got ur idea. But it still abstract to me. Any idea/key words or similar question you've seen before that I can google it? Thank you very very much!

Comment: Nothing comes to mind right now. Sounds like it's just a general "how would I shard it" question.